# Unable to boot into Mac OS after installing Fedora[Dual Boot]

Tags: fedora, partition, osx, dual-boot, fdisk

I installed Fedora on my Mac and now when I boot, it says "booting in insecure mode" an then see a typical Linux "choose what to boot" screen.

The List goes like:

*Fedora
Fedora Recovery
Mac OSX 32-bit
Mac OSX 64-bit
Mac OSX 32-bit
Mac OSX 64-bit*

Fedora starts just fine, but when I go to one of the four Mac options, it tells me some commands weren't found(I can look up which, if needed).

The Mac partitions were left completely untouched during installation.

Output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 146AB7C4-3FB6-46B2-8538-3747383C9946

Device           Start          End   Size Type
/dev/sda1           40       409639   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2       409640    391034639 186.3G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda3    391034640    392304175 619.9M Apple boot
/dev/sda4    392304640    392816639   250M Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda5    392816640    413296639   9.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6    413296640    423536639   4.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda7    423536640    956016639 253.9G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.9 GiB, 2041577472 bytes, 3987456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5513338d

Device    Boot     Start       End Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdb1 *            0   1951743 975872   0 Empty
/dev/sdb2            172     10235   5032  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3          10284     50603  20160   0 Empty


Disk /dev/sdb1: 953 MiB, 999292928 bytes, 1951744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5513338d

Device      Boot     Start       End Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdb1p1 *            0   1951743 975872   0 Empty
/dev/sdb1p2            172     10235   5032  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb1p3          10284     50603  20160   0 Empty
```

So, I thought, the active Partition was set wrong, but fdisk itself tells me that the command a does not exist and then, I tried it with parted, but that does not work either

```
# sudo parted /dev/sda1 set 1 boot on
Error: The flag 'boot' is not available for loop disk labels.
# sudo parted /dev/sda3 set 1 boot on              
Error: The flag 'boot' is not available for loop disk labels.
```

I had once installed Debian on the Mac, and it automatically booted into Linux, but when I pressed alt, I was able to access the reFind menu and boot into Mac OS.
This does not work here, I just get the same "booting in insecure mode" message and so on.

Also, the Fedora Partitions were supposed to be ext4, so I have no idea why it says Microsoft basic data.

Comment: is the file `/sys/firmware/efi` present?

Comment: I was able to access OSX by installing reFind on Fedora. I did a new install, same problems. I'll go with the reFind Solution mentioned, even if it is not very clean. Still, I'd like to know if there is any clean solution for the problem.